# Method execute in android.os.AsyncTask not mocked error, but not actually mocking anything

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to write a test for a class of my that extends `AsyncTask` but I keep getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method execute in android.os.AsyncTask not mocked
```

even though I am NOT trying to use a mock or spy at all.

Here is my test kotlin test class:

```
import org.junit.Test

class VerbixTranslatorTest {

    private var verbixTranslator = VerbixTranslator();

    @Test
    fun shouldTranslationRegularVerbs() {
        var s = verbixTranslator.getConjugations("infinitive")

    }
}
```

and here is the actual Java class, if it even matters

```
public class VerbixTranslator extends AsyncTask<String, String, Verb> {

    public Verb getConjugations(String presentTense) {

        try {
            return execute(presentTense).get();//execute and wait until the call is done
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Verb doInBackground(String... data) {

        // do stuff
    }

}
```

I have also tried adding the following:

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

but that seems to cause my method to always return null and not actually enter the `doInBackground` method...

Why am I getting this error when I not mocking anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got around this moving the logic from `doInBackground` to a helper method and then calling that helper method instead from my test.